# Others => '1' statement in Verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I have used VHDL all my life and only been using Verilog for a short time, I have to create a logic in Verilog for a very large array and assign it to 1 or 0 depending on the condition of an input.

Here is my VHDL code

```
 if (data_track == '1' ) then
            my_array(MAX-1:MIN) <= (others=> '1');
 else
            my_array(MAX-1:MIN) <= (others=> '0');
 end if;
```

MAX and MIN are parameters for the block, set during the synthesis depending on the type of system we are accessing.

Is there a way to do this in Verilog easily?

Comment: It's not VHDL. A slice name  discrete range is either a range attribute or 'simple_expression direction simple expression', where direction is either `to` or `downto`. while `':'` is a delimiter. We can tell my_array is a single dimensional array type with a base type comprised of character literal enumerations. The right hand side expressions are aggregates where all element values are either `'0'` or `'1'`. The type of the aggregate is derived from the left hand side, in this case purported to be a constrained array subtype. The use of a slice name may be superfluous here. Show declarations.

Comment: Also there is no `==` operator in VHDL.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - And the parentheses in the if statement condition are superfluous. (I was out of comment characters).

Comment: His question is straightforward and easy to understand despite small syntactic issues that crop up when writing psuedocode instead of VHDL intended for compilation. This is one of those rare cases where pointing out non-critical syntax issues is a waste of time because the OP wants to write in verilog in the end anyway, not VHDL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mix of parameter with curly braces will help in resolving (the inner curly brace will act as replication operator)

Code eg:

```
    parameter MAX = 16;

    assign high_val = 1'b1;
    assign low_val = 1'b0;

    if ( data_track ==1'b1) 
    my_array[MAX-1:MIN] <= {MAX{high_val}};
    else
    my_array[MAX-1:MIN] <= {MAX{low_val}};
```

Here in the above code the if statement with curly brace will propogate MSB to LSB with 1 values resulting in all 1's in our case 16 then result will be a 16'b1111111111111111 and it is the vice versa for else condition

Comment: Thanks a lot, with some minor modification it worked.

Comment: If you don't mind upgrading to system verilog then you can assign all ones with `<= '1` and all zeros with `<= '0`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `data_track` is one bit wide, then this can be collapsed into one line by replicating the `data_track` input and assigning it to `my_array`:

```
assign my_array[MAX-1:MIN] = {(MAX-MIN){data_track}};
```

Comment: And in VHDL `my_array(MAX - 1 downto MIN ) <= (others => data_track);`